# Measuring performance of python code without affecting it

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I want to know how much time does it take to publish and getting the response back. I can use the code to do that, but the problem with this code is that to take `t1` and `t0`, some time is getting consumed and which will affect the overall t0 to response time.

Is there an alternative way to take time stamps which run in parallel to main code without affecting it?

```
diff=[]
t0=[];=t1=[];response_time=[]
while i<1000:
    response_rcvd=False
    t0.append(time.time())
    client.publish()
    t1.append(time.time())
    diff.append(t1-t0)
    while not response_rcvd:
        pass
    response_time.append(time.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this scenario, I see no proven way of doing this completely independent of the main process but lets see the alternatives.

**1. Use timing decorators:** This involves using something like

```
@timer
def my_func()
    pass
    # enter code here
```

Where `@timer` is the decorator that records the function timing.
A comprehensive tutorial can be found [here](https://realpython.com/python-timer/)

**2. multiprocessing:** 
The first alternative I would advise you to look into is using `multiprocessing` module [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html); 
This involves putting the main function in one process and the timing recorder function on another and then using some of its shared-state methods like `multiprocessing.Event` to send timing events from the main process to the timer process.
I doubt if this completely solves your problem after-all, methods like `event.set()` will also spend some time just like the `time.time()` you are running away from.

**3. timing time.time():**
If your main goal is accuracy of timing, The second alternative would involve you timing how much `time.time()` actually takes from your program and taking it in consideration when making your final calculations.